# ubuntu throws this error: error found when loading /home/user/.profile user.name has multiple values, cant access to my laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .profile

i have an issue about ubuntu, when i try to login to my user, i got this error:
[see the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfwH4.jpg)

the message:
warning: user.name has multiple values error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change user.name.

i can successfully login to my second user, i tried to reset my git username but doesn't work

can any one help about this problem ?

Comment: Stack overflow is a programming Q&A site. Your question did not belong to it!

Comment: only programmers can get this error, and as you see it's related to git, hope you can help.

Comment: Then please post your text in the question. Following links to pictures is not good style.

Comment: Thank you for you response, sorry for the lake of information, i fixed the problem by changing git global user.name hope i can help someone with the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i have fixed the problem by changing my git username and email :

git config --global --replace-all user.name "mario"

git config --global --replace-all user.email "mario@gmail.com"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).